# Закрытие вопроса по неверной причине

Tags: обсуждение

**Проблема:**
Закрыт вопрос [Что такое + в Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1423149/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2-python) по причине: "вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой". Так как в вопросе  спрашивается про использование `+` в языке, то очевидно, что ни опечаткой, ни невоспроизводимостью тут и не пахнет. Я попробовал его переоткрыть, несколько подправив текст  чужого вопроса, и даже прямо написав, что нет тут таких причин, но получил сообщение: "повторное открытие сообщения провалилось: Исходные причины закрытия не были исправлены". С моей точки зрения это совершенно неверно, названных причин вообще нет.

**Правильный ход событий с моей точки зрения:** переоткрытие, и возможное закрытие по верной причине, если таковая найдется, и сообщество проголосует за неё.

**Вопросы:**

*1) Это нормальная практика русскоязычного сообщества, закрывать по неверной причине, да так, что непонятно, как переоткрывать? (англоязычное сообщество отличается, кстати?)*

*2) Я тут что-то могу сделать ещё?*

**Комментарий:** я не настаиваю, что этот вопрос должен обязательно оставаться открытым, если большинство считает, что он не нужен в базе знаний. Хотя моё мнение, что если кому-то странный вопрос и пришёл в голову, пусть и от нежелания почитать учебник, то он и другим  прийти может, и в базе знаний он поэтому нужен (я и на работе так всегда действую, и коллеги согласны с подходом).
Но если уж и закрывать, то по нормальной причине, а не по надуманной.

Мне, кстати, действительно было интересно ответить автору, я такими ответами своё знание языка углубляю.

Comment: Вы как-то сильно перелопатили вопрос, но должен признать, теперь он более адекватный. Плюсанул переоткрытие.

Comment: @Kromster, спасибо. Я его под достаточно адекватные ответы перелопачивал, по факту. Сам вопрос был плохо сформулирован и, возможно, автор даже не прочитал, что ему 3 человека написали, так как принятого ответа нет:-) Но вот почему такую странную причину закрытия выбрали?

Comment: Не могу сказать, т.к. я закрывал по причине "непонятна суть", но видимо её "поглотила" другая причина, за которую было больше голосов.

Comment: @Kromster, ясно, спасибо, да, суть я и перелопачивал для переоткрытия.

Comment: Я один из тех, кто голосовал против, переоткрытия. Вопрос может быть действительно популярным, но формулировка очень уж кривая (субъективно). Сейчас никак не голосую в очереди на переоткрытие. Как сообщество решит, так и будет. @Сергей раз уж вы ратуете за наполнение базы знаний, так может и ответ шире дать?

Comment: В англоязычном сообществе всё то же самое: закрывают вопросы абы как.

Comment: @Dmitry, 1) но вопрос-то у меня был в этой теме: почему закрыт с причиной "вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой", а далее не переоткрыли с комментарием "Исходные причины закрытия не были исправлены"? Какие опечатки и невоспроизводимости в `+`?2) Надо понимать, что мои собственные знания тоже не очень глубоки. Посмотрел сейчас, с учетом остальных данных ответов даже не знаю, что ещё имеет смысл написать там. На  такой вопрос достаточно, на мой взгляд.

Comment: @Сергей ввести немного терминологии для строк, например (конкатенация). Не только пример привести, но и объяснить от чего это зависит. Привести пример для встроенных типов данных. Зачем складывать булевы значения, почему они себя так ведут при данном операторе. Так то можно на хорошую статью растянуть;)

Comment: @Надо понимать, что мои собственные знания тоже не очень глубоки. Глубже я пока не полезу, это на следующем витке.